# jQuery(...).autoComplete is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to get autoComplete() to work from jQuery-ui. I've created a fiddle to show my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/4s4dzwn1/

My JS:

```
jQuery(function(){

    jQuery('#autocomplete').autoComplete({
        source: ["ActionScript",
            "Bootstrap",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Ecommerce",
            "Jquery",
            "Groovy",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lua",
            "Perl",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Swing",
            "XHTML"]
    });

});
```

My HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input id="autocomplete">
</form>
```

It's throwing an error that says autoComplete is not a function. My understanding is that autoComplete is a part of jQuery-ui (which is included), and that jQuery-ui should be included **after** jquery. Please correct me where I'm wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you're spelling the method correctly? case and all? *([you aren't](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/))*

Comment: To expand on @KevinB, `autoComplete` isn't part of jQuery UI, `autocomplete` is.  Case matters.

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked that and it is now working correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This code

```js
jQuery(function(){

    jQuery('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source: ["ActionScript",
            "Bootstrap",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Ecommerce",
            "Jquery",
            "Groovy",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lua",
            "Perl",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Swing",
            "XHTML"]
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <form>
        <input id="autocomplete">
    </form>
```

Comment: This solution worked for me

Comment: Way late to the party, but for others looking for an answer to this: we are using JQuery 3.3.1 and you also need to use jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js  "autocomplete" requires the "ui".